# Closed set in uniform norm?

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open set of $\mathbb R^d$ and consider the space $C^1(\overline \Omega)$ equipped with the norm
$$
|| f || = \max_{x \in \overline \Omega} |f(x)| + \sum_{j=1}^d \max_{x \in \overline \Omega} |\partial_j f(x)|.
$$
Moreover, consider the set $A := \{ f \in C^1(\overline \Omega) \mid (\exists \, g \in C(\overline\Omega)) \ f=x_1 g \quad \text{in} \quad  \overline \Omega \}$.

Is $A$ closed set?

I've tried taking $\{f_n\}_{n\geq 1} \subset A$ such that $||f_n-f|| \xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$, for some $f \in C^1(\overline \Omega)$, but I haven't been able to show that $f=x_1 g$, for some $g \in C(\overline\Omega)$.

This impossibility to show my statement just make me think that maybe it is false. Although, I haven't found a counterexample yet.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, by the form of the norm, it is complete, so if $f_n$ is a cauchy sequence, then the limit is in the space. So convergence=cauchy sequence. That fact also establishes that $g$ is in the space. And a set $S$ is closed in a normed space if every convergent sequence of elements in the set $S$, has the limit in the set $S$, so if we gave us a convergent sequence, it is the same thing as if we gave us a cauchy sequence.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f_n$ be a sequence of functions in $A$, that its also a cauchy sequence. Since $f_n=x_1 g_n$ where $g_n\in C(\bar{\Omega})$ (C is just continous or differentially continuous? I am confused by the notation, since I think it should be the second one). Since $f_n$ is cauchy it's not hard to see that $g_n$ is also cauchy (since we are in a compact set). So $g_n\rightarrow_u g$, then consider $\Vert x_1 g-f+f_n-f_n\Vert$ by triangle inequality follows that they are the same function.

Comment: Ok, by the form of the norm, it is complete, so if $f_n$ is a cauchy sequence, then the limit is in the space. So convergence=cauchy sequence. That fact also establishes that $g$ is in the space. And a set $S$ is closed in a normed space if every convergent sequence of elements in the set $S$, has the limit in the set $S$, so if we gave us a convergent sequence, it is the same thing as if we gave us a cauchy sequence.